# Laravel only delete a model if no related model exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Lets say i have a model called 'manufacturer' and this model has one to many relation with another model 'vehicle'. Now i dont want to let users delete a manufacturer if there are any vehicles associated with this model.

```
//In Manufacturer model

public function vehicles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Vehicle');
}
```

And in the repository/controller i have another method to check for it.

```
public function checkAssociatedVehicles($id)
{
    return Manufacturer::with('vehicles')->find($id)->toJson();
}
```

**This does outputs the manufacturer data with all the associated vehicles. but this is not efficient, so i just want to check that if there is even one vehicle then dont delete the manufacturer.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you'd want to use the `has` method to make sure the manufacture has some vehicles.

```
$manufacture = Manufacturer::has('vehicles')->find($id);
```

Then you'd just want to make sure `!is_null($manufacture)`

Comment: `has()` us used for eager loading, which is not really what needs to happen here. Instead I would just count the vehicles without fetching them. Assuming the `$manufacturer` model has been fetches and the `vehicles` relationship method has been added to the model: `$manufacturer->vehicles()->count()`

Answer (score 2):

As you have a `vehicles()` method in your Manufacturer model, you may just do this:

Use the `whereDoesntHave` method to filter all Manufacturers without vehicles before deleting them:

```
Manufacturer::whereDoesntHave('vehicles')->get();
```

From the [API](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_whereDoesntHave):

> Add a relationship count condition to the query with where clauses.

Answer (score 1):

You can return the count of total vehicles like this:

```
  return [
      'count' => Manufacturer::with('vehicles')->find($id)->count()
  ];
```

Now you can just check the count.

Answer (score 1):

This will return boolean on whether there is an vehicles on the manufacturer.

```
return (Manufacturer::with([
    'vehicles'=> function($query){
        return $query->limit(1);
    }])->find($id)->vehicles);
```

You can add foreign key and prima key on the vehicles to reduce the number of column being query for performance concern.

```
return $query->limit(1)->select('id','manufacturer_id');
```