# Laravel - Delete if no relationship exists

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Below is the one of the model. I would like to delete a Telco entry only if no other model is referencing it? What is the best method?

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Telco extends Model
{
    public function operators()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Operator');
    }

    public function packages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Package');
    }

    public function topups()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Topup');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\User', 'owner');
    }

    public function subscribers()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Subscriber', 'App\Operator');
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to check existence of every other table records referencing the foreign key while deleting.

Comment: If your relationships are correct try deleting it and caching the exception (which would fire if the model has childrens)

Comment: @SagarGautam that would be a long method, is there any efficient short form of it?

Comment: @Mohammad, You have to check existence of record in every related model. It's better to define a boolean function in `Telco` model. When you want to delete call this function, and delete data when no related data exists.

Comment: May be your answers is in this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136141/laravel-only-delete-a-model-if-no-related-model-exist

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `deleting` model event and check if there any related records before deletion and prevent deletion if any exists.

In your `Telco` model

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($telco) {
        $relationMethods = ['operators', 'packages', 'topups', 'users'];

        foreach ($relationMethods as $relationMethod) {
            if ($telco->$relationMethod()->count() > 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where to use this method? Controller or Model?

Comment: In your Telco model

Answer (score 4):

```
$relationships = array('operators', 'packages', 'topups', 'users', 'subscribers');

$telco = Telco::find($id);
$should_delete = true;

foreach($relationships as $r) {
    if ($telco->$r->isNotEmpty()) {
        $should_delete = false;
        break;
    }
}

if ($should_delete == true) {
    $telco->delete();
}
```

Well, I know this is ugly, but I think it should work. If you prefer to un-ugly this, just call every relationship attributes and check whether it returns an empty collection (meaning there is no relationship)

If all relationships are empty, then delete!

Answer (score 1):

After seeing the answers here, I don't feel copy pasting the `static function boot` to every models that need it. So I make a `trait` called `SecureDelete`. I put @chanafdo's `foreach`, inside a `public function` in `SecureDelete`.

This way, I can reuse it to models that need it.

`SecureDelete.php`

```
trait SecureDelete
{
    /**
     * Delete only when there is no reference to other models.
     *
     * @param array $relations
     * @return response
     */
    public function secureDelete(String ...$relations)
    {
        $hasRelation = false;
        foreach ($relations as $relation) {
            if ($this->$relation()->withTrashed()->count()) {
                $hasRelation = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($hasRelation) {
            $this->delete();
        } else {
            $this->forceDelete();
        }
    }
}
```

Add `use SecureDelete` to the model that needs it.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Traits\SecureDelete;
class Telco extends Model
{
    use SecureDelete;

    public function operators()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Operator');
    }

    // other eloquent relationships (packages, topups, etc)
}
```

`TelcoController.php`

```
public function destroy(Telco $telco)
{
    return $telco->secureDelete('operators', 'packages', 'topups');
}
```

In addition, instead of `Trait`, you can also make a custom model e.g `BaseModel.php` that extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, put the `function secureDelete` there, and change your models to `extends BaseModel`.

Comment: if hasRelation gives true means it is present in a record, then shouldn't it be prevented from deleting the model? I don't understand that part

Comment: @FeRcHo yes, by default it you want to delete data that has relation to other table, the program will throw database error and http status 500. My code is just check if the relation exist and soft deletes it, or hard delete it if no relation exist.

Comment: OP doesn't want to delete the record soft or hard. if relation does exist